# Symfony2 Syntax Errors (in vendor files)

Tags: php, symfony, syntax, vendor

To maintain code integrity across our servers we'd like to keep the /vendor/* directory under source control, rather than use composer to download files each time we roll out onto another server - i.e. we can be certain that the /vendor/* files are identical.

We run a syntax checker against all files committed to source control and run across the following error:

```
File '/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Resources/skeleton/bundle/Bundle.php' failed the PHP syntax check with the following error:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting T_NS_SEPARATOR in /vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Resources/skeleton/bundle/Bundle.php on line 3
```

Is the "error" in this file intentional ? Any help appreciated. File contents below:

```
<?php
namespace {{ namespace }};

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class {{ bundle }} extends Bundle
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "error" in this file is intentional as it is not really to be proceed by php "as is". It is a template used by the command `app/console generate:bundle` to generate a bundle.

So `{{ namespace }}` will be replaced by a real namespace and `{{ bundle }}` by the bundle name you choose when you generate the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for this, kinda what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

First you must check if `php/bin` is on your `$PATH`.

`PATH=$PATH: /your/path/to/php/bin`
`export PATH`

Besides make sure that PHP can execute with CLI (in shell with `exec`).

Second check your server requirements, which are for running Sympony2:

You can easily see if your system passes all requirements by running the web/config.php in your Symfony distribution. Since the CLI often uses a different php.ini configuration file, it's also a good idea to check your requirements from the command line via:

`php app/check.php`

#### Required:

1. PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.3.2
2. Sqlite3 needs to be enabled
3. JSON needs to be enabled
4. ctype needs to be enabled
5. Your PHP.ini needs to have the date.timezone setting

#### Optional:

1. You need to have the PHP-XML module installed
2. You need to have at least version 2.6.21 of libxml
3. PHP tokenizer needs to be enabled
4. mbstring functions need to be enabled
5. iconv needs to be enabled
6. POSIX needs to be enabled (only on *nix)
7. Intl needs to be installed with ICU 4+
8. APC 3.0.17+ (or another opcode cache needs to be installed)
9. PHP.ini recommended settings
   9.1. short_open_tag = Off
   9.2. magic_quotes_gpc = Off
   9.3. register_globals = Off
   9.4. session.autostart = Off

If you want to use Doctrine, you will need to have PDO installed. Additionally, you need to have the PDO driver installed for the database server you want to use.

Comment: You are welcome, could you provide more of this file in your question by editing it?

Comment: How does that relate to syntax checking of that file?

Comment: If you download the framework I wouldn't think that it has bugs in it, I would start checking the server first and paid attention to requirements.

Comment: The framework operates fine, I'm not suggesting it has bugs. The issue is when I commit to our source control servers the PHP is syntax checked - it's completely possible that the syntax error found is deliberate and required but I'd like to understand why

Comment: Well, my friend, you must expect a bunch of reasons for this. If I got you correctly, I must say that if PHP has syntax errors, it will always be there on all servers - it's not warnings that can be switched off. Are you saying that errors appeared when you moved to the other server?

Comment: Nope - the error is found in our syntax checker - it doesn;t appear to be valid PHP syntax

Comment: Did you always encountered it or after certain changes?

Comment: Syntax checker will probably behave the same based on the server settings?

Comment: I don't see how this is related in any way to the server environment or the Symfony pre-requisites! I simply wanted to know if anyone could explain the syntax in the file above and if/why it's required

Comment: I'm off here without seeing the server settings. Where do you run your Syntax checker? If you run it on the same server, I think, it will not help you much, just because  in order to execute it, it will have to face same server requirements that are needed for your framework. If it's not what you have expected to get, then I'm  sorry not being able to help you out more.